# Moving average of last 10 hours in graphite

Tags: graphite

I have to draw the average of data points of last 10 hours. I get a data point for every 5 minutes, so essentially i have to draw the average of last 12*10 data points. 
Suppose i have "delay" as a data point, at every point it makes more sense to draw average of last 10 hours delay instead of plotting the current delay.

I tried ***Average(),sum() and summarize()*** functions but i guess they do not achieve this functionality.

Any help on this?

Comment: What about `summarize()` did not fit your requirement?

Answer (score 4):

Can you take advantage of the **[movingAverage](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.movingAverage)** function within graphite?

An example for the 10 hours of the a moving average would be the below.

```
&target=movingAverage(datapoint.name.deplay,'10hour')
```